# git rebase -i HEAD~7 -- showing only "noop" in editor

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I am trying to squash a commit which is at HEAD into one that is a few back. When I run `git rebase -i HEAD~7`, however, I am presented with just a `noop` in the editor! I am totally confused about how this is supposed to work.

I am working in a branch (`cleanup`) that I created (using `checkout -b cleanup ...` on the SHA1 I found in `reflog`) after I had my first `rebase` experience and I accidentally deleted all of those commits; point is, I am not sure what the branch's parent is (if that matters, here).

I am simply trying to do what I have read about many times: I want to modify slightly some commited code that isn't the most recent commit. Whether that's an application for "squashing" or just amending it when I get to that point, I don't know.

I am also seeing this on STDOUT as the editor starts after running the rebase command shown above:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~7
usage: git rev-list [OPTION] <commit-id>... [ -- paths... ]
  limiting output:
    --max-count=<n>
    ...
```

In addition to the `HEAD~7` reference, I have tried specifying the entire SHA1, and different refspecs to local and remote branches. Same result for everything...

What am I missing? Thanks for your help!

---

#### Edit:

```
$ git log --oneline HEAD~7..HEAD
d0fd20e temp Fix resume_cities table
ea2ffdf Fix db/seeds.rb to reflect recent database structure modifications
dbd2b8b Add several models/scaffolds that go along with the Geonames tables
9759091 Fix name of the ResumeSkill model file.
3fc3134 Added the SHA1 for the previous commit to the comments on the migration, to help link back to that.
bacbeb2 Consolidate database migrations! READ ME!
0c49a57 Moved back to gem versions of linkedin, omniauth, and twitter
```

It's the `bacbeb2` commit I want to amend with the `d0fd20e`

---

Per the recommendation of @MarkLongair, I added `set -x` to `/usr/lib/git-core/git-rebase--interactive` and saw the following strange output:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~7

[... output muted for brevity, see the full output, here: http://gist.github.com/1163118]
+ read -r shortsha1 rest
+ sed -n s/^>//p
+ git rev-list --no-merges --cherry-pick --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --abbrev=7 --reverse --left-right --topo-order 2c51946812a198ca908ebcad2308e4b8274624b3...d0e9ff6d9c1f8bc374856ca2a84ad52d6013b5bf
usage: git rev-list [OPTION] <commit-id>... [ -- paths... ]
  limiting output:
    --max-count=<n>
    --max-age=<epoch>
    --min-age=<epoch>
    --sparse
    --no-merges
    --remove-empty
    --all
    --branches
    --tags
    --remotes
    --stdin
    --quiet
  ordering output:
    --topo-order
    --date-order
    --reverse
  formatting output:
    --parents
    --children
    --objects | --objects-edge
    --unpacked
    --header | --pretty
    --abbrev=<n> | --no-abbrev
    --abbrev-commit
    --left-right
  special purpose:
    --bisect
    --bisect-vars
    --bisect-all
+ test t = 
+ test -s /home/ryan/Projects/social-jobs/.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo
+ echo noop
[...]
```

I say, 'strange output' because if I run the `rev-list` command directly from my shell, it works as expected:

```
$ git rev-list --no-merges --cherry-pick --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --abbrev=7 --reverse --left-right --topo-order 2c51946812a198ca908ebcad2308e4b8274624b3...d0e9ff6d9c1f8bc374856ca2a84ad52d6013b5bf
>0c49a57 Moved back to gem versions of linkedin, omniauth, and twitter
>bacbeb2 Consolidate database migrations! READ ME!
>3fc3134 Added the SHA1 for the previous commit to the comments on the migration, to help link back to that.
>9759091 Fix name of the ResumeSkill model file.
>dbd2b8b Add several models/scaffolds that go along with the Geonames tables
>ea2ffdf Fix db/seeds.rb to reflect recent database structure modifications
>d0e9ff6 !temp Fix resume_cities table !temp
```

Comment: What version of git are you using?  What is the output of `git log HEAD~7..HEAD`?  (The latter command is what's used to produce the list of commits that are considered for rebasing - the behaviour you're seeing is probably because this list is empty for some reason - possibly a bug, or something very odd about your repository.)

Comment: I see this behavior with Git 1.7.4.1, (from the Ubuntu repos).

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw, @mark-longair, but edited the question with the output of `git log HEAD~7..HEAD`. Git seems to be able to assemble that list just fine. I'm totally stumped, here. Is there any sense to clone my repo to start fresh, or is this not that type of problem?

Comment: It's worth trying, I suppose, but the behaviour you point out is puzzling enough that I would be interested to get to the bottom of it!  I've added an answer with some suggested ways of diagnosing what's going wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue **was caused by** my .bashrc **setting IFS:**

```
# remove the space character from IFS
# (http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html#IFS)
IFS="`printf '\n\t'`"
```

I cannot remember at all why I put that in there. I'm sure it had something to do with 'fixing UNIX/Linux filenames' as indicated by my inclusion of that URL. Dunno.

Regardless, though, I removed that statement and: POOF! **No more problem!**

Thanks so much to @MarkLongair for his help!

Comment: Does this strike anyone as being a bug? It was my understanding that a shell script, in general, ought not to rely on that type on environment variable unless it has explicitly set the variable itself.

Comment: Maybe you should ask that at the git mailing list: git@vger.kernel.org.

Comment: Ah, that explains everything :)  I'm glad to hear you've sorted that out - I've updated my answer with an explanation of why this setting of `IFS` breaks the script.

Answer (score 12):

*Update:* There's an explanation for this behaviour at the end of my answer, but I've left the debugging suggestions here in case they are of use to anyone.

---

I'm not sure I have a real answer here, but I'll explain what's happening to the best of my understanding.  When invoked as `git rebase -i HEAD~7`, git should only output `noop` to `.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo` if that file is empty or does not exist.  We know that this isn't a permissions problem, since that file (containing "noop" and the commented lines) is successfully created as a result.  The fact that you see an error from `git rev-list` on the terminal also suggests that the problem is really due to how `git rev-list` is invoked.  In git v1.7.4.1, with the command line you quote, the list of commits to include should be found from the following:

```
git rev-list --no-merges --cherry-pick --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit \
    --abbrev=7 --reverse --left-right --topo-order HEAD~7...HEAD
```

Note that this is somewhat different from what is suggested by the man page (`git log <upstream>..HEAD`) since the range uses `...` instead of `..`

I would guess, since you see an error from `git rev-list`, that this is the problematic command.  Could you try that, and see what the output is?  If that seems to work, then I suspect that there is an earlier error that causes this command line to be malformed.  Since the interactive rebase is implemented as a shell script, you can fairly easily investigate this by editing the script with `sudo editor /usr/lib/git-core/git-rebase--interactive` and adding `set -x` at the top, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
#
# Copyright (c) 2006 Johannes E. Schindelin

# SHORT DESCRIPTION
[...]
```

Then if you try running `git rebase -i HEAD~7`, you should see every command that the script is running, and possibly see what's wrong with the `git rev-list` invocation.

I hope that's of some help.

---

*Update:* It [turns out that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137985/git-rebase-i-head7-showing-only-noop-in-editor/7154025#7154025) the problem here was the the questioner had `IFS` set to only include tab and newline, rather than the default of space, tab and newline.

This causes a problem in the line in `git-rebase--interactive` beginning:

```
git rev-list $MERGES_OPTION --pretty=oneline [...]
```

... since `MERGES_OPTION` is set to `--no-merges --cherry-pick`.  With the default value of `IFS` (which includes space) this will be split into two parameters after the variable is substituted.  However, with an `IFS` that doesn't include space, `--no-merges --cherry-pick` will be interpreted as a *single*, and obviously unknown, argument, causing the `git rev-list` usage message and empty output being passed on in the script.

A good puzzle :)

Comment: Good tip. I tried that... no less confusing now. The `rev-list` command that is printing it's usage while being called from `rebase` works without a hitch when called directly (see above). This must be something to do with an environment variable (and by that I mean, a factor that may change given a different environment, not `env`) that I am not aware of.

Comment: I should add that I am using RVM to manage my Rubies. That, I think, does a lot of low level stuff to the shell, like overriding `cd`. I'm going to try the `rebase` in a shell that hasn't loaded rvm and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Could you possibly add to your question the output that you get on the terminal with the modified script?

Comment: Well I tried it on an other machine, same git version, using a clone of the repo that I was having trouble with. Worked perfectly. There is a lot different about this other machine when compared to my dev box, so it's hard to say, but it doesn't have RVM on it... I think I'll install it there to see if that breaks git again...

Comment: RVM doesn't seem to be at fault here. I installed it on the other machine, `rebase` still works great. I even tried `rsync -ra` the repo's directory to that machine (I figured maybe git was fixing the problem during the `clone`)... no problems there. The local repo I have is totally fine, by my reasoning. I am working on reinstalling git and all the dependencies I can afford to remove temporarily. I think it must be something to do with the git installation...

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser.  I don't suppose you have any of the GIT_ environment variables set on the problematic machine?

Comment: Nowadays a bad `IFS` is not likely to cause the reported problem.  AFAIK, all common shells ignore `IFS` from the environment and explicitly set it to <space><tab><newline> at startup.  Also, all Git versions since v1.7.11.6 explicitly (un)set `IFS` (via `git-sh-setup`) to defend against shells that do inherit `IFS` from the environment.