# Using git rebase --interactive on a repo cloned from subversion

Tags: macos, git, osx-mountain-lion, rebase

I have several repos that have been converted from SVN. Each time I attempt to run `git rebase -i master`, the message defaults to `noop`. When saving, I get `Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master` which seems suggest it has done something, but all commits are still present.

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137985/git-rebase-i-head7-showing-only-noop-in-editor) but the solution doesn't appear to apply to OsX.

I also tried `git rebase -i HEAD~3` on a project with 3 commits, but I get:

`fatal: Needed a single revision`

Using `rebase -i HEAD~2` will and rebases correctly, but I need to squash these to a single commit with the init commit date.

Interestingly, the rebase consistently misses the earliest commit on each project. In each it it the only commit not assigned to my user (it is a system commit), so I wonder if that is related.

Answer (score 1):

The [question cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137985/git-rebase-i-head7-showing-only-noop-in-editor) has a possible answer: Setting the shell variable IFS (what characters are interpreted as separating "words" in shell lines, in this case separating arguments) makes two arguments interpreted as one (obviously unknown), and the (internal) command fails with the cited result.

See to what (if anything) IFS is set (`echo $IFS`). Try `(unset IFS; git rebase -i HEAD~3)` (the parentesis are required here in bash(1), OS X shell could be different, but I doubt it).

Comment: No effect. Same issue. echo $IFS just adds a blank line

Comment: Perhaps run `sh -x /usr/libexec/git-core/git-rebase ...` (here it is a script, this should spit out the commands executed, and might give a clue). **Experiments only in scratch repos, please**.

Comment: `sh: /usr/libexec/git-core/git-rebase: No such file or directory`

Comment: OK, find out where git is hiding the *real* commands (`git` is just a wrapper that calls them).

Comment: ran locate git-rebase, found a few options. Tried running them, no joy yet. Hmmmm...